# Prism for Xamarin, dependency failed for INavigationService

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, prism

I am working on a sample Xamarin.Forms App for iOS, using PRISM.

But when I tried to use INavigationService in ViewModel, it is failed saying dependency failed for interface INavigationService

I dont know what wrong I am doing, how can we get around it or is it a bug in INavigationServices injection.

Thanks
Divikiran Ravela

Heres the code

```
    public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        Prism = new PrismBootStrap();
        Prism.Run(this);
    }

    public class PrismBootStrap : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override Page CreateMainPage()
    {
        return new NavigationPage(Container.Resolve<HomePage>());
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<HomePage, HomePageViewModel>();
    }
}


    public class HomePage : ContentPage
    {

        public HomePageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }


   public HomePage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.Prism.Container.Resolve<HomePageViewModel>();
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Hello ContentPage" }
            }
        };
    }
}


public class HomePageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public HomePageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService; //Fails here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INavigationService depends on the use of the ViewModelLocator.  If you don't use it, then the service cannot be injected.  Instead of manually resolving your VM, use the ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel attached property.  Besides, you don't want to be using your container like that.  You only want one composition root when using DI.

Also, I recommend using the latest 6.1 preview.  It has a ton of navigation improvements.

Comment: Thanks the for the input Brain, appreciate it. Hey I am not using XAML pages to have AutowireViewModel set to true on along with other namespaces. I am using contentpage.cs, I tried SetValue(ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel, true) on page ctor. But still I was having same issue. Can you please direct me with some sample code.

Comment: You need to use ViewModelLocator.SetAutowireViewModel because it is an attached property.

Comment: I tried below 
//SetValue(ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModelProperty, true);
  ViewModelLocator.SetAutowireViewModel(this, true);

Not working yet, please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Make sure you are following the ViewModelLocator namespace conventions.  View must be located in a Views namespace, and ViewModel must be in a ViewModels namespace.

Comment: This might help: http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/

Comment: Thanks Brain for the valuable inputs, its working.
All I had to do was SetValue(ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModelProperty, true);

Comment: What about if I want to eager load a view model (IEnumerable models)? If a viewmodel can only be resolved through wireup that is impossible.

Comment: How would you do it normally?  And no it's not impossible.